# Elegant way to find closest value in a vector from above

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need a function that takes a vector (assumed to be sorted), and a value, and returns the closest number that's [edit] <strike>greater than</strike> less than or equal to that number, preferably using an algorithm from the STL. I have come up with a solution using std::lower_bound(), but it seems kludgy and ugly:

```
struct ClosestCmp {
    bool operator()(const int & x, const int & y) { return x > y; }
};

// vec is assumed to be sorted
int closest(const std::vector<int> & vec, int value)
{
    std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator cri =
        std::lower_bound(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), value, ClosestCmp());
    if (cri != vec.rend()) {
        return *cri;
    }
    return -1;
}

// ...
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(5);
std::cout << closest(vec, 2) << "\n"; // Should ouput "2"
std::cout << closest(vec, 3) << "\n"; // Should ouput "2"
std::cout << closest(vec, 4) << "\n"; // Should ouput "4"
```

Can anyone suggest a way that's more elegant, maybe using an STL algorithm without needing a comparison function or a reverse iterator? I have looked in the STL, but haven't been able to find a better solution than this.

Comment: 2 is not greater than or equal to 3, I guess you wanted 4 to be printed ?

Comment: Correction: I need the closest number that's *less than* or equal to the value, not greater. My bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` with binary predicates that match the order of the container. So, you can't sort by `<` and then use a different binary predicate (say `<=` or `>`). So your "kludge" is actually the correct thing to do. The sorted vector in reverse is the ordering criteria you want to use to find the element less than or equal to the value. (Otherwise, if you were actually searching for the value greater than or equal to, you could just use `std::lower_bound`.)

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. The STL is mostly designed to use the `<` operator only, and nothing else.

Comment: STL algorithms deal with sorted ranges based on a binary predicate. The default predicate is `<`. As long as the predicate defines an ordering, the algorithms work.

Comment: providing an example is always good i believe.

Answer (score 32):

For reminder:

- `std::lower_bound`: returns the first value that does not compare less
- `std::upper_bound`: returns the first value that compares strictly greater

From your description, `std::lower_bound` already looks like the perfect fit, what is wrong with:

```
int closest(std::vector<int> const& vec, int value) {
    auto const it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    if (it == vec.end()) { return -1; }

    return *it;
}
```

Which is used as:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(4);

    std::cout << closest(vec, 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << closest(vec, 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << closest(vec, 4) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
4
```

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer however OP's question is contradictory.

Comment: You are correct. I meant to say *less than*, not greater than, the value. Thank you.

The output, therefore, needs to be:

    2
    2
    4

Answer (score 9):

Requires C++11:

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename ValueType>
InputIterator closest(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, ValueType value)
{
    return std::min_element(first, last, [&](ValueType x, ValueType y)
    {   
        return std::abs(x - value) < std::abs(y - value);
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not benefit from the fact that the vector is sorted. Complexity is always linear

Comment: Yes, that is true. But it is elegant :)

Comment: If sorted one can use lower_bound siblings, but this is a nice solution for non sorted containers.

Comment: This solution works better if closest is used in the sense of smallest difference with value. For vector `{1, 4}`, `closest(2)` returns `1`, `closest(3)` returns `4`.

Answer (score 0):

For the largest which is less or equal one can use this function

```
int closest(std::vector<int> const& vec, int value) {
    auto const it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    if (it == vec.begin()) { return -1; }
    else return *(it - 1);
}
```

Comment: I considered this solution. However, it fails if the first element of vec equals value.